# Javascript and php execution priority in different browsers

Tags: javascript, php

I have a simple JS statement, which kind of "protects" me from using special characters in a login form on my website:

```
$("#login_button").click(function(){
    formChecker();
});

function formChecker() {

    var checkLogin = document.forms["loginForm"]["username"].value;

     if ((checkLogin.indexOf("!") > -1) || (checkLogin.indexOf("@") > -1) || (checkLogin.indexOf("#") > -1)) {
        alert("Special characters not allowed! Please use A-Z and numbers.");
        document.location = "http://mywebsite.com/";
    }
}
```

It works fine in Chrome. Whenever someone is using one of these characters, he is getting redirected instantly, so the php login script is not executed.

The problem occures when I am using it in Internet Explorer. It actually redirects my page but the php script is executed anyway. I have also tried `window.location` but it doesnt work at all in IE. What is the problem with this browser? Is the scipt priority different in different browsers?

What I mean is that on IE, even though the user is redirected, when he comes back to the website, he is logged in, but he shouldnt be. The chrome browser does not log in the user because page is redirected and it is how it should work.

Comment: It is php script that logs in the user into the system. It is really long so i didnt posted it. In IE, when you type a special character, you are getting redirected but when you go back to the previous website you are logged in anyway.

Comment: php is running server side it should run before the js is called. so depending on that php, im not surprised by whats happening here

Comment: You could shorten your validation quite a bit: `if (checkLogin.match(/[!@#]+/g)) { ...`

Comment: Yea, but this JS is executed when you press submit button. And the php executes after submitting. Anyway, the js should stop the browser from sending php query since it is redirecting the website before the php query is sent right? The IE is different.

Comment: @RobM. Great suggestion, thank you!

Comment: no php loads server side before the browser sees one iota of the js

Answer (score 2):

This is not how to do form validation. There is no guarantee that `click` will be called on the button (eg the form might be submitted by pressing Enter); you aren't preventing the form from being submitted by doing a redirect (it's a race condition which might happen first); and also alert-and-redirect is pretty user-hostile.

You should be picking up the `submit` event on the form itself, and cancelling the event if you don't want the form to submit. For example add a div with `id="formErrorMessage"` to the page and then:

```
var goodUsernamePattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$/;

$('#loginForm').on('submit', function(event) {
     if (!goodUsernamePattern.test(this.username.value)) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $('#formErrorMessage').text('Please enter a good username blah');
     }
});
```

Comment: The thing is that there is no average submit button. It is `<a>` link programmed to log in the user into the system. It also does not work with enter button. The problem is that the website is very complicated and there are more functions connected to this link so i dont want to change it much by myself. Anyway I am plus rating your message for nice suggestions :)

Comment: Well, you can similarly `event.preventDefault()` in the `click` handler of the `<a>`  to stop the link being followed... although if that link is actually triggering some other JavaScript code to make the form submit, you will need to change *that* code to stop it doing anything; there is no way to say that one event handler gets a look in (and chance to stop the event) before the other event handler. In general it's usually a bad idea for accessibility and usability to use a link to act as a submit button. You can style a button to look like a link if you don't like the appearance.